# Ruby on rails form_for and uncountable models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

```
<% form_for(@software) do |f| %>
```

is producing a form tag that looks like this:

```
<form action="/software.%23%3Csoftware:0x24b2eac%3E" ...
```

The software model is a bit special, in that I've made it uncountable (softwares didn't sit well with me)

```
environment.rb:
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w( software )
end
```

but I did name a singular form to get the routes working

```
map.resources :software, :singular => :software_item
```

Modifying form_for like so:

```
<% form_for(@software, :url => software_item_path) do |f| %>
```

produces the correct output, so perhaps I'm going about the whole uncountable thing the wrong way? Is there generally a better way use models with the same singular and plural word?

Comment: What is the code in the controller that creates @software?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old but I had a similar issue on Rails 4.1.
According to the [Inflection doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-uncountable), `inflect.uncountable` should define:

> [...] uncountable words that shouldn't be attempted inflected.

This however is insufficient for some reason (I'll dive in the source and have a look and see what's going on once I have time)

Anyway, using `inflect.irregular` instead of `inflect.uncountable` in `config/initializers/inflections.rb` seems to do the trick

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'software', 'software'
end
```

Comment: Just for the record - this does NOT seem to work with rails 5